# How do I create a responsive website design?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in the process of designing a website and I want it to work with all screen resolutions.

Here is an example of what I want.

http://www.fork-cms.com/

My question is, what is the best way to code something like this?

Would I do something like

```
if(resolution < 768px)
   //resize page and or move elements around
else if(resolution == 1080px)
   ////resize page and or move elements around
```

Comment: Trust me, rewriting your entire site is not a great idea in this situation. What you could do instead is make all lengths, widths, and all other sizes defined on the page in percentages, instead of pixels. Then they would auto-adjust to the screen size :)

Comment: I was thinking about doing this, but using the website on mobile will have the same look as desktop which sometimes is not desirable. I want mobile experience to look a little different and I want to do this without having to create a mobile version of a website.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too man :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Bootstrap.  It's a framework based on HTML5 and CSS3 developed by Twitter for creating responsive web sites.  See http://getbootstrap.com/.

Comment: I was looking into bootstrap, specifically the grid system and I feel like when I resize my browser, certain grids will just move to the next line. Is there a way I can select where it moves to?

Comment: Changing the location of elements in the page can be changed by the responsive Bootstrap column classes.

Comment: This is the exact reason I made my grid system below so it could be more flexible to what I needed it to do (no pun intended). When I started learning responsive design a lot of the classes names didnt make sense to me.. (i.e. col-6 col-6). They rely on a "12 column layout". Mine relies on a percentage based layout that equals to 100% always so instead of "col-6 col-6" mine is "col50 col50" to equal 100% across,, not a column limit. It was just easier for me, all boils down to preference.

Answer (score 1):

Css media queries targeting industry standard cut off points is usually the way to go.
One common implementation of this is bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simple grid system based off of a few popular ones such as golden grid system and boostrap. check it out and start playing w/ it: http://oneillwebs.com/grid/

click the (download) link to get a full version of it.